# Having trouble loading from a text file C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble loading from a text file to a value. I want it to load from the text file, but the number remains unchanged.

Data.txt

```
7
7
```

Line 1 of the file is Health, what I'm trying to load.

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player
{
    public:
        int Health;
        int MaxHealth;
        Player() { this->Health = 9; this->MaxHealth = 9; }
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void save_to_file(string filename, Player P)
{
    ofstream f( filename.c_str() );
    f << P.Health << endl;
    f << P.MaxHealth << endl;
}

bool load_from_file(string filename, Player P)
{
    ifstream f( filename.c_str() );
    f >> P.Health;
    f >> P.MaxHealth;

    return f.good();
}

int main()
{
    Player P;
    load_from_file("Data.txt", P);
    cout << P.Health << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks! I just learned C++ so I'm a little confused. I'm running Codeblocks and 'Data.txt' is in the 'bin' folder.

EDIT :

Changed main.

```
bool load_from_file(string filename, Player& P)
{
    ifstream f( filename.c_str() );
    f >> P.Health;
    f >> P.MaxHealth;
    if(f.good()){
        cout << "Sucess!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }
    return f.good();    
}
```

Comment: `save_to_file` is never called.

Comment: You don't test, if the file was ever opened correctly. Also `load_from_file()` should take the `Player` parameter by reference.

Comment: Why are you class variables public? Why not use initialiser lists?

Comment: You may see a different result if you pass a reference to P..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing wrong if you followed πάντα ῥεῖ's advice, but this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
  int Health, MaxHealth;
};

void save_to_file(string filename, const Player& P)
{
    ofstream f( filename.c_str() );
    f << P.Health << endl;
    f << P.MaxHealth << endl;
}

bool load_from_file(string filename, Player& P) {
  ifstream f( filename.c_str() );
  f >> P.Health;
  f >> P.MaxHealth;
  if(f.good()){
    cout << "Success!" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Failure" << endl;
  }
  return f.good();
}

int main() {
  Player P;
  load_from_file("Data.txt", P);
  cout << P.Health << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function signature to take the parameter by reference:

```
bool load_from_file(string filename, Player& P) {
                                        // ^
```

As is, your function only modifies a copy of the `Player` parameter, and the result isn't seen in `main()`.

Comment: @O81000 Please post additional information in your question, not in comments.